# Как для каждого блока задать свой цвет?

Tags: css, sass

Без верстки нет особого смысла вдумываться об идее
Я выложил верстку тут:
https://jsfiddle.net/kLfzb1nd/

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
      accordion : false // A setting that changes the collapsible behavior to expandable instead of the default accordion style
    });
  });
```

```css
.collapsible-header {
  background: rgba(255,248,224, 1);
}

.collapsible {
margin: 0; padding: 0; box-shadow: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="collapsible"  data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li class="active">
  <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
        
       <ul class="collapsible"  data-collapsible="accordion">
          <li class="active">
          <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1->Child1</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">

             <ul class="collapsible"  data-collapsible="accordion">
              <li class="active">
              <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1->Child1->Child1</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body">

                 1

              </div>
              </li>
              <li class="active">
              <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1->Child1->Child2</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body">

                 2

              </div>
              </li>
             </ul>

          </div>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
          <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1->Child2</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">

             2

          </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
      
    </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
 
 <ul class="collapsible"  data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li class="active">
  <div class="collapsible-header">Parent2</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
        
        2
      
    </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
 
 <ul class="collapsible"  data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li class="active">
  <div class="collapsible-header">Parent3</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
        
        3
      
    </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Есть дерево элементов, вложенность может быть огромной, но я не понимаю, как унифицировать задачу

```
Parent1
---Child1
------Child1-Child1
------Child1-Child2
---Child2

Parent2

Parent3
```

Задача сделать так, чтобы каждый родительский блок отличался цветом (родительских блоков может быть и тысяча, так как данные и DOM генерируется на стороне бэкэнда), хотя бы альфа каналом (уменьшать чуть-чуть прозрачность), но как это можно сделать не используя JS?

Реальная ситуация такая, дело в том, тут непонятно кто является родителем дочернего элемента (если делать внутренние margin, то инпуты едут)

Такое же можно заметить и в верстке на jsfiddle
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непонятно, как дочерние элементы соотносятся с родительскими блоками, поэтому было предложено уменьшать у дочерних элементов альфа-канал больше, но опять же, как это сделать на CSS?

Comment: Во время генерации страшной вложенности сгенерируйте и тег style с цветами для нее. В момент генерации вы ведь будете знать глубину и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут пригодится универсальный селектор `*`. Благодаря ему можно наследовать цвет на дочерних элементах, постепенно увеличивая степень прозрачности за счет наложения.

Количество поддерживаемой вложенности регулируется шагом прозрачности.
Уменьшите стартовое значение в примере ниже, если нужна большая вложенность.

```
.collapsible {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.collapsible * {
  background: rgba(255, 248, 160, .15);
}
```

Вот полный пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible({
    accordion: false // A setting that changes the collapsible behavior to expandable instead of the default accordion style
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .collapsible {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .collapsible * {
    background: rgba(255, 248, 160, .15);
  }
</style>
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">

      <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li class="active">
          <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1->Child1</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">

            <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
              <li class="active">
                <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1->Child1->Child1</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body">1</div>
              </li>
              <li class="active">
                <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1->Child1->Child2</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body">2</div>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <div class="collapsible-header">Parent1->Child2</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">2</div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="collapsible-header">Parent2</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">2</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="collapsible-header">Parent3</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```